# Internal storage files location

Tags: android, internal-storage

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Ok so the above code creates a file in the internal storage and writes something into it. My question is, where can I find and open this file in Eclipse? I want to see its contents and edit it manually. Or I may want to include my own file and read its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, where can I find and open this file in Eclipse?

Using the file manager in the DDMS perspective, for the default user account on an emulator, go to `/data/data/your.application.id.goes.here/files`, substituting in the `package` from your manifest where I have `your.application.id.goes.here`.

Comment: Thank you, I searched but couldn't find. One more question, why doesn't it add it in the 'res' folder? Or what's the difference between files in res folder and internal storage?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc: "One more question, why doesn't it add it in the 'res' folder?" -- because there is no `res/` folder. That is something in your source code of your project. It is not something that exists on the filesystem in the device, but rather is packaged as part of the APK. "what's the difference between files in res folder and internal storage?" -- it's largely the same as the difference between icons baked into a Windows EXE and a hard drive. One is part of a program, the other is where files created by the program might go.