# How can i find my app's files?

Tags: android, file-browser

I m trying to find my app's files with FileBroswer but I dont see into /storage/sdcard0/Android/data my app's pakage name, so i cant find my file which i created with this code :

```
void insertToFile()
{
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("TrustedDevicesNamesDataFile", Context.MODE_APPEND);
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream));

        str.append(checkId + "~" + name + "\n");
        bufferedWriter.write(str.toString());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            bufferedWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27907886/115145

Answer (score -1):

The file you created by `openFileOuput` is located on `/data/data/your_package_name/files`, so you can't see in `/storage/sdcard0/Android/data`.

If you want to write your file to `SDCard`, you should declare sdcard write permission on your `AndroidManifest.xml` like below and create the file explicitly instead handling by `openFileOutput`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```